# Adding Flutter to Existing Apps: libflutter.so missing in the APK for "armeabi-v7a"

Tags: android, flutter

I an android project in native android. I created a module inside my project inside which I am writing my code in flutter based on docs:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
build.gradle for my app looks like:

```
...
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.something.somethingelse"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode vcode
        versionName "1.0." + vcode
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
          signingConfig null
          ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
        release {
            signingConfig null
            minifyEnabled true
            testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), '../android-lib/proguard-rules.pro', '../android-lib/proguard-test-rules.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), '../android-lib/proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    // Refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits
    splits {

       // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
       abi {

         // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
         enable true

         // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
         // want APKs for x86 and x86_64.

         // Resets the list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for to none.
         reset()

         // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
         include "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a"

         // Specifies that we do not want to generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
         universalApk false
       }
    }

        // Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
    def abiCodes = ['x86':1, 'x86_64':2, 'armeabi-v7a':3, 'arm64-v8a':4]

    // APKs for the same app that all have the same version information.
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        // Assigns a different version code for each output APK.
        variant.outputs.each {
            output ->
                def abiName = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                output.versionCodeOverride = abiCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 100000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
```

When I look at APKs generated in the APK analyzer, apks for "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a" contain libflutter.so but apk for "armeabi-v7a" doesn't contain libflutter.so. I am using latest version of flutter i.e. 1.9.1

Due to missing libflutter.so for this apk, application crashes on some of the devices which use "armeabi-v7a". Is there known fix for this issue? How can I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: I've raised a github issue for the same. 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43248